# org.json.JSONException: Value ��������������������

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

Estoy tratando de llenar un spinner con datos de mysql utilizando web services php que me devuelven un JSONArray, el problema es que me esta devolviendo el error que dice el titulo.

```
private class consultarDatos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";

        }
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        JSONArray ja = null;
        try {
            ja = new JSONArray(result);

            IdProvincia = ja.getInt(0);

        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

He probado el archivo php y me devuelve el JSONArray bien, la app funciona bien en el emulador pero en los teléfonos físicos no.

Esta es la excepción que arroja.

```
org.json.JSONException: Value ���������������������������
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
```

Aqui esta el metodo DownloadUrl:

```
  private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;

    // Aqui es importante reemplazar los espacios por %20
    myurl = myurl.replace(" ", "%20");

    // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
    // web page content.
    int len = 5000;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("Respuesta", "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
        return contentAsString;

        // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
        // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}

public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, 
UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error indica el valor que se trata de procesar:

> org.json.JSONException: Value ���������������������������

El valor que indica el LogCat, .no es un valor JSONArray :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        JSONArray ja = null;
        try {
            ja = new JSONArray(result);

            IdProvincia = ja.getInt(0);

        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

asegura que el metodo siguiente en realidad obtenga una respuesta tipo JSONArray.

```
return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
```

Comment: Disculpa, soy nuevo en esto de programación android, he probado la respuesta que da mi archivo php y me devuelve el JSONArray perfectamente, no se como probarlo de otra manera.

Comment: Estaba revisando mi archivo php, modifique un nombre en mi base de datos que contenía una "ñ" y funciona todo bien si no hay ñ en el los nombres que traigo en el arreglo, como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Según lo que comentas podría ser un problema de codificación, prueba a devolver la información desde tu php en codificación UTF-8

Comment: @AngelGrullon agrega tu método downloadUrl()

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a codificar en *UTF-8*:

```
ja = new JSONArray(URLEncoder.encode(result, "UTF-8"));
```